# What is "tab.active" in chrome's cpu profiler output?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiler

I'm seeing significant cpu time spent by "tab.active" inside some anonymous function that doesn't have a location. Does anyone know what that is?

[image: chrome profiler tab.active]